# Load and Display View While Interstitial is Shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, admob, interstitial

I have a UiViewController1 that loads an Admob interstitial, displays it when the user clicks a button, and loads another UiViewController2 when the user clicks out of the ad. However, I don't want the previous viewController to show, and the Admob interstitials are presented animated (I don't know of a way to stop this):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-7102519969826764/7522738211";
    interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,@"TheIDAppearingInLogs",nil];
    [interstitial loadRequest:request];   
}

-(void)onButtonPush {
    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    } else {
        UIViewController2 *viewController = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    UIViewController2 *viewController = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I tried to load UIViewController2 before the ad is dismissed but, this happens:

```
Attempt to present <UIViewController1: 0x1355816a0> 
on <UIViewController2: 0x135506490> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: did you try to load your "another" viewController on didDIsmiss adMob delegate?

Comment: @Injectios Yes, but because of the dismiss animation on the interstitial, the previous view controller shows before the other viewcontroller is loaded

Comment: give us a bit portion of code to clarify your expectations

Comment: @Injectios ok I doing that right now

Comment: in case if interstitial NOT is ready and you present "fake" vc everything is fine?

Comment: @Injectios sorry Was using the names that for my view in my app

Comment: so issue solved? If not you should check presentedViewController of your first vc in didDismiss delegate

Comment: @Injectios it wasn't solved those were the real names. I just am referring to them as viewController 1 and 2 in this example

Comment: @Injectios what about the presentedViewController

Comment: check your viewController1.presentedViewController property it should be nill

Comment: @Injectios the code works but it shows viewController1 before presenting viewController2

Comment: ahhh.. got it. You CANNOT modify AdMob SDK's viewController presenting, actually what you are doing is not really common. I would suggest do some workaround f.e adding your viewController2 as a child instead of presenting modally in didDismiss delegate

Comment: @Injectios thanks for staying with me. I will try that and get back.

Comment: @Injectios It worked! Post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct, or I can post it if you want.

Comment: thanks, wish you luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you CANNOT modify `AdMob` SDK's viewController presenting behaviour, 
actually what you are doing is not really common.

I would suggest to do some workaround f.e adding your viewController2 as a child instead of presenting modally in `interstitialdidDismiss` delegate